# pass the data from controller to view without route as the view I am showing in a pop-up

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am working on a laravel4 , I have a registration form which I have included in a footer because when the user click on the register button , I can show the form as a pop-up . So the user can click the register button on any other pages . In my registration , I have a drop down and the values i want it from a database .

```
public function action_editUser() {
                $data = array(
                    'departments' => '0',
                    'department_id' => '1');
                return View::make('home.reg_pop',array('data' => $data));   
            }
```

So I have made a dummy function(passing a temporary data ) in my controller and I can't have a route for this method because I am showing a registration form as my view in a pop-up . So is there any way to pass the value to my view or any other way which can solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about view composers. I think that may be the answer to your question. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers

It should allow you to always pass some data/additional view every time some other view is being used.